# How to perform a task in certain time?

Tags: java, android, scheduled-tasks

I need a command that can perform something, lets say on 7:00 AM every day.

Is it possible?

I would appreciate if you could give me some code samples

Thank you!

Comment: 'Please provide code' questions are not a good idea on SO...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need the AlarmManager class, you create an intent and a calendar object (set to the time you want), then use AlarmManager to run the intent at that time (using setRepeating to make it repeat every day)

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(),
                                some_service.class);
                        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent
                                .getService(getBaseContext(), 0, intent, 0);


                        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                        // Cancel all previous alarms of the same type
                        alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);


                        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                        Calendar currentDate = Calendar.getInstance();

                        calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR, 24);
                        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 07);
                        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
                        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);

                        // Set alarm manager to run at selected time
                        // each day
                        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC,
                                calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                                AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
```

Comment: Thanks! but do I need the class to extend something?

Comment: AlarmManager is a system class, so you can just put this code into your main class to utilise it, no need to extend anything.

Comment: I meant to the intent. Does it have to extend Service?
When it doesn't extend anything it doesn't work

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not quite sure what you mean. AlarmManager runs the PendingIntent at the certain time you specify. You can set the PendingIntent to run an Intent to start an Activity, or start a Service, whatever you want. In my example I start a Service, "some_service.class", and in that class you do need to extend Service. If you don't want to use a service you could alternatively have a class which extends Activity, in which case you would change pendingIntent to .getActivity(). The same goes for .getBroadcast (extends BroadcastReceiver)

Answer (score 0):

Problem is your application will not be running 24/7.
But incase it is, you can use Java's Timer Class to implement your task. [See Documentation here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html).